# MySQL - Assign numbers based on value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to replicate what I'm achieving with the code below, but without using CASE:

```
CASE
WHEN c.Path LIKE '/Local/Activities%' THEN 2
WHEN c.Path LIKE '/Local/Automotive%' THEN 3
WHEN c.Path LIKE '/Local/Beauty & Spas%' THEN 4
WHEN c.Path LIKE '/Local/Food & Drink%' THEN 5
WHEN c.Path LIKE '/Local/Health & Fitness%' THEN 6
WHEN c.Path LIKE '/Local/Personal Services%' THEN 7
ELSE 8
END AS Category
```

I have 6 main Categories, which I have assigned numbers to with this CASE.
I want to do the same for my sub Categories, however, I have about 100 of those, which would make writing a CASE quite tiresome, and prone to mistake.

How would I go about assigning those sub Categories number values without using CASE and without having to write a huge amount of code?

I have tried to find a solution here or elsewhere online, but have yet to find anything relating to my question.

NOTE: I only have Read access to this database.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a lookup table:

```
create table pathCategories (
    pathCategoryId int auto_increment primary key,
    prefix varchar(255)
);

insert into pathCategories (prefix)
    values ('/Local/Activities'),
           ('/Local/Automotive'),
           . . .;
```

Then the query would look like:

```
select t.*, pc.pathCategory
from t left join
     pathCategories pc
     on t.path like concat(pc.prefix, '%');
```

Comment: might be a good solution, but it is relocating the problem as instead of writing all those case end conditions you now have to write 100 inserts (values).. This solution is less error prone still that is still about the only advantage over the case end method the topicstarter had so + 1 ..  also i doubt there is a better solution as this is most likely the best there is.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that I only have read access to this database (have added it to the main question now), but in that case I guess there's no other option than just using the Case?

Comment: *"NOTE: I only have Read access to this database."* That was very important to know from the start, we could have told you that there wasn't a other solution @MichielvanDijk